# ¿Se puede configurar Google Chrome por línea de comando o script?

Tags: chrome, administración-de-software

Estoy trabajando en una empresa con alrededor de 65.000 usuarios/equipos en 5 países y necesito configurar Google Chrome (cosas como permitir pop ups, agregar un link de confianza, etc) y hacerlo equipo por equipo seria una tarea herculeana
yo podria hacer este trabajo con algun script o por linea de commandos (bat).

Comment: ¿Tu organización tiene un dominio de GSuite? Parecería que no por tu pregunta, pero es la mejor forma de hacerlo, dándote estas opciones -> https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2657289?hl=en

Comment: Y jamás lo hice, pero me imagino que algo de este estilo es lo que estás buscando: https://www.chromium.org/administrators/complex-policies-on-windows

Comment: sii gracias es algo parecido a eso le hechare un vistaso para ver si resulta muchas gracias, nosotros usamos ad

Answer (score 1):

## Respuesta corta

Sí se puede hacer la configuración "masiva" de múltiples instalaciones de del navegador de Google mediante **Chrome for Work**.

## Explicación

Existen dos versiones de Chrome, Chrome "a secas" y Chrome for Work. La primera está orientada a "consumidores", es decir, usuarios que por su cuenta instalan y configuran Chrome típicamente en unos cuantos dispositivos, la segunda está orientada a las necesidades de empresas e instituciones que tienen una persona o área responsable de la administración de hardware y software.

Algunas de las opciones de administración requieren de G Suite pero otras no. Puedes encontrar todos los detalles por medio de las páginas enlazadas en las referencias.

## Referencias

- [Chrome for Work](https://enterprise.google.com/chrome/chrome-browser/) (Página del producto)
- [Cómo configurar Chrome for Work](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/188446?hl=es) (artículo de ayuda)

Answer (score -1):

Hasta donde yo sepa no, googleando dos minutos los resultados tampoco me muestran que se pueda hacer eso.

> configurar google chrome

Lo que si puedes hacer es usar un correo de **GMAIL**  y hacer los ajustes necesarios en un navegador de Chrome. Para cuando descargues Chrome en otra PC e inicies sesión con ese correo se te configurará igual que en la PC inicial.

Claro que cualquier cambio que una persona haga en su navegador usando la CUENTA DE CONFIGURACIÓN afectará a las demás.

Comment: si lo que pasa es que todos los usuarios tendrian que tener mi cuenta gmail para que funcione de esa manera y reinstalar todos los browser en los equipos de los usuarios no lo veo muy factible, lo que si vi fue algo de la master_preference o por gpo de chrome pero tampoco entiendo muy bien